# random number generator

Tags: android, random

I m trying to make a random number generator in android. My code has to start generating numbers in sets of 3 after clicking the "generate" button. So far i've coded a generator that can produce finite sets of 3 numbers each. What i want to create is a dynamic generator that keeps generating numbers.CODE:
`

```
public class Plot2Activity extends Activity {  
 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.main);

   final Random myRandom = new Random();

   Button buttonGenerate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.generate);
   final TextView textGenerateNumber = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.generatenumber);

   buttonGenerate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

  @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   ArrayList<Object> Arry1 = new ArrayList<Object>();
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
   ArrayList<Integer> Arry = new ArrayList<Integer>();
   for(int k=0;k<3;k++){
       Arry.add(myRandom.nextInt(100));
   }
       Arry1.add(Arry);
   }
       textGenerateNumber.setText(String.valueOf(Arry1));
       }
       });  
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the same process in a loop and update an array from a background thread. For background thread look below link this may help you.

However if you don't want to generate frequently, Put a sleep() in your background thread for a second and than let it update your Array.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Happy coding,

Krio

Article which may help,

http://www.dailygeek.de/using-asynctask-to-update-a-listactivity/

Above article shows how you can update your ListActivity in similar fashion you may update your Array.

Lets say create an activity which has AsycTask, and create a separate class such as,

```
public class RandomNumbers{}
```

Above class will have an Array list of numbers being generated,

And update this class's object from Background which eventually available to your UI Thread too. I hope I and clear enough.

Comment: Do not forgot to Accept my answer if you like it! Thanks, Just a click on a green tick on your my answer's left side

Comment: Can you post a small sample...as to how do I update from the backgroud thread...I am having trouble with the linking.